# Averaging database values from multiple columns, bypass zeroes/null

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to save an average based off of the values in several different columns, but some rows are null so they need to be replaced with zero. Also, at that point, I need the average to factor in the zeroes so that the example below would save the avg as "82.490". So it needs to replace null with zero, and then bypass any zeroes for the average.

```
1CorrectAcc  2CorrectAcc  3CorrectAcc  4CorrectAcc  5CorrectAcc  avg
   90.345        67.890       89.234       0              0
```

This is a pseudo query

```
UPDATE staging
SET `avg` = (1CorrectAcc + 2CorrectAcc + 3CorrectAcc + 4CorrectAcc + 5CorrectAcc) / COUNT avoiding zeroes
```

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the values are in column aggregation function can't be used

```
(
    coalesce(col1, 0) + 
    coalesce(col2, 0) +
    ...
) / (
    case when coalesce(col1, 0)=0 then 0 else 1 end +
    case when coalesce(col2, 0)=0 then 0 else 1 end +
    ...
)
```

If in a row all columns are 0 or null, a division by 0 error will be raised, it can be avoided adding following condition in where clause to filter these rows.

```
[where/and] not (
    coalesce(col1, 0) = 0 and
    coalesce(col2, 0) = 0 and
    ...
)
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit lost there (I'm very unfamiliar with SQL currently): So, I don't ever know if one of the corrected accuracies is a percentage or null, but I just need to have the overall average on the front end. So If I were to preform an average of all 5 tests above, but wanted to factor in the possibility of a field being null, I would just use the first part of your answer?I'm just a bit confused on how to structure it exactly.

Comment: the second part is to avoid error when a record can contain 0 or null for all values in this case the divisor will be 0

Answer (score 1):

Normalise your schema:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,account_id INT NOT NULL
,value DECIMAL(7,3)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,1,90.345),
(2,1,67.890),
(3,1,89.234),
(4,1,NULL);

 SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+------------+--------+
| id | account_id | value  |
+----+------------+--------+
|  1 |          1 | 90.345 |
|  2 |          1 | 67.890 |
|  3 |          1 | 89.234 |
|  4 |          1 |   NULL |
+----+------------+--------+

SELECT account_id, ROUND(AVG(value),3) FROM my_table GROUP BY account_id;
+------------+---------------------+
| account_id | ROUND(AVG(value),3) |
+------------+---------------------+
|          1 |              82.490 |
+------------+---------------------+
```